std::move a boost::flat_map of unique_ptr
I want to be able to initialize a class that holds a boost::container::flat_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AbstractBaseClass>> in the constructor. Example:
class MapHolder {
public:
   MapHolder(boost::container::flat_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AbstractBaseClass>> &&map):
   _map(std::move(map)) {}

private:
   boost::container::flat_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AbstractBaseClass>> _map;
};

MapHolder m({
   {"test", std::make_unique<ConcreteDerivedClass>("val")}
});

I keep getting the error that it is trying to copy the unique_ptrs instead of moving them. Is there any way I can fix this?
===== EDIT =====
So I see that my post was closed and marked as duplicate. They link to another post, but the problem is that it's for a vector of unique_ptrs and I don't know if it will work for a boost::container::flat_map and/or how to modify it so that it does.
If someone could show me how to get it working for my case that would be great.
Also, I have included a minimal reproducible example as requested, followed by compiler error:
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
   virtual ~Base() = default;

   virtual int getMember() const = 0;

protected:
   int _mem() const { return someMember; }

private:
   int someMember = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   ~Derived() override = default;

   int getMember() const override {
      return _mem();
   }
};

class MapHolder {
public:
   MapHolder(boost::container::flat_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Base>> && map):
   _map(std::move(map)) {}

private:
   boost::container::flat_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Base>> _map;
};

int main() {
   MapHolder m({
      {"test", std::make_unique<Derived>()},
      {"test2", std::make_unique<Derived>()}
   });

   return 0;
}

Compiler error:
[build] /usr/bin/g++ -DBOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT -I/home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include -m64 -Wall -pedantic -flto=auto -fPIC -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -fexceptions -fcoroutines -g3 -D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -std=c++2a -MD -MT test/CMakeFiles/qtest.dir/qtest.cpp.o -MF test/CMakeFiles/qtest.dir/qtest.cpp.o.d -o test/CMakeFiles/qtest.dir/qtest.cpp.o -c ../../test/qtest.cpp
[build] In file included from /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:29,
[build]                  from /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/flat_map.hpp:29,
[build]                  from ../../test/qtest.cpp:1:
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::container::dtl::pair<T1, T2>& boost::container::dtl::pair<T1, T2>::operator=(const boost::container::dtl::pair<T1, T2>&) [with T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; T2 = std::unique_ptr<Base>]’:
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/construct_in_place.hpp:67:10:   required from ‘void boost::container::assign_in_place(DstIt, InpIt) [with DstIt = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; InpIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/copy_move_algo.hpp:839:40:   required from ‘typename boost::container::dtl::disable_if_memtransfer_copy_assignable<I, F, I>::type boost::container::copy_n_source(I, U, F) [with I = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; U = long unsigned int; F = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; typename boost::container::dtl::disable_if_memtransfer_copy_assignable<I, F, I>::type = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/advanced_insert_int.hpp:91:55:   required from ‘void boost::container::dtl::insert_range_proxy<Allocator, FwdIt>::copy_n_and_update(Allocator&, Iterator, std::size_t) [with Iterator = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; FwdIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/copy_move_algo.hpp:1445:40:   required from ‘typename boost::move_detail::disable_if_c<boost::container::dtl::is_single_value_proxy<InsertionProxy>::value, void>::type boost::container::expand_forward_and_insert_nonempty_middle_alloc(Allocator&, F, F, std::size_t, InsertionProxy) [with Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; F = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; InsertionProxy = boost::container::dtl::insert_range_proxy<boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >, const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*>; typename boost::move_detail::disable_if_c<boost::container::dtl::is_single_value_proxy<InsertionProxy>::value, void>::type = void; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/copy_move_algo.hpp:1483:54:   required from ‘void boost::container::expand_forward_and_insert_alloc(Allocator&, F, F, std::size_t, InsertionProxy) [with Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; F = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; InsertionProxy = boost::container::dtl::insert_range_proxy<boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >, const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*>; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/vector.hpp:3059:10:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/vector.hpp:2088:45:   required from ‘boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::iterator boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator, FwdIt, FwdIt, typename boost::move_detail::disable_if_or<void, boost::move_detail::is_convertible<InIt, typename boost::container::allocator_traits<typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type>::size_type>, boost::container::dtl::is_input_iterator<FwdIt> >::type*) [with FwdIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; T = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; A = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; Options = void; boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::iterator = boost::container::vec_iterator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*, false>; boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator = boost::container::vec_iterator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*, true>; typename boost::move_detail::disable_if_or<void, boost::move_detail::is_convertible<InIt, typename boost::container::allocator_traits<typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type>::size_type>, boost::container::dtl::is_input_iterator<FwdIt> >::type = void; typename boost::container::allocator_traits<typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type>::size_type = long unsigned int; typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:923:62:   required from ‘void boost::container::dtl::flat_tree<Value, KeyOfValue, Compare, AllocatorOrContainer>::insert_unique(InIt, InIt) [with InIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Value = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; KeyOfValue = boost::container::dtl::select1st<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:1488:29:   required from ‘void boost::container::dtl::flat_tree<Value, KeyOfValue, Compare, AllocatorOrContainer>::priv_range_insertion_construct(bool, InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Value = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; KeyOfValue = boost::container::dtl::select1st<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:691:43:   required from ‘boost::container::dtl::flat_tree<Value, KeyOfValue, Compare, AllocatorOrContainer>::flat_tree(bool, InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Value = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; KeyOfValue = boost::container::dtl::select1st<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/flat_map.hpp:347:8:   required from ‘boost::container::flat_map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>::flat_map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, T> >) [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; T = std::unique_ptr<Base>; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = void]’
[build] ../../test/qtest.cpp:40:5:   required from here
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:367:14: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Base; _Dp = std::default_delete<Base>]’
[build]   367 |       second = p.second;
[build]       |       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/memory:76,
[build]                  from ../../test/qtest.cpp:2:
[build] /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:469:19: note: declared here
[build]   469 |       unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
[build]       |                   ^~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:29,
[build]                  from /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/flat_map.hpp:29,
[build]                  from ../../test/qtest.cpp:1:
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::container::dtl::pair<T1, T2>::pair(const boost::container::dtl::pair<T1, T2>&) [with T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; T2 = std::unique_ptr<Base>]’:
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:422:10:   required from ‘static void boost::container::allocator_traits<Allocator>::priv_construct(boost::move_detail::false_type, Allocator&, T*, Args&& ...) [with T = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; Args = {const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >&}; Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; boost::move_detail::false_type = boost::move_detail::integral_constant<bool, false>]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:367:42:   required from ‘static void boost::container::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(Allocator&, T*, Args&& ...) [with T = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; Args = {const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >&}; Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/construct_in_place.hpp:37:63:   required from ‘void boost::container::construct_in_place(Allocator&, T*, InpIt) [with Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; T = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; InpIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/copy_move_algo.hpp:585:46:   required from ‘typename boost::container::dtl::disable_if_memtransfer_copy_constructible<I, F, I>::type boost::container::uninitialized_copy_alloc_n_source(Allocator&, I, std::size_t, F) [with Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; I = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; F = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; typename boost::container::dtl::disable_if_memtransfer_copy_constructible<I, F, I>::type = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/advanced_insert_int.hpp:85:75:   required from ‘void boost::container::dtl::insert_range_proxy<Allocator, FwdIt>::uninitialized_copy_n_and_update(Allocator&, Iterator, std::size_t) [with Iterator = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; FwdIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/copy_move_algo.hpp:1474:54:   [ skipping 3 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/vector.hpp:2088:45:   required from ‘boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::iterator boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator, FwdIt, FwdIt, typename boost::move_detail::disable_if_or<void, boost::move_detail::is_convertible<InIt, typename boost::container::allocator_traits<typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type>::size_type>, boost::container::dtl::is_input_iterator<FwdIt> >::type*) [with FwdIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; T = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; A = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; Options = void; boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::iterator = boost::container::vec_iterator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*, false>; boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator = boost::container::vec_iterator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*, true>; typename boost::move_detail::disable_if_or<void, boost::move_detail::is_convertible<InIt, typename boost::container::allocator_traits<typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type>::size_type>, boost::container::dtl::is_input_iterator<FwdIt> >::type = void; typename boost::container::allocator_traits<typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type>::size_type = long unsigned int; typename boost::container::real_allocator<T, A>::type = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:923:62:   required from ‘void boost::container::dtl::flat_tree<Value, KeyOfValue, Compare, AllocatorOrContainer>::insert_unique(InIt, InIt) [with InIt = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Value = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; KeyOfValue = boost::container::dtl::select1st<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:1488:29:   required from ‘void boost::container::dtl::flat_tree<Value, KeyOfValue, Compare, AllocatorOrContainer>::priv_range_insertion_construct(bool, InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Value = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; KeyOfValue = boost::container::dtl::select1st<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/flat_tree.hpp:691:43:   required from ‘boost::container::dtl::flat_tree<Value, KeyOfValue, Compare, AllocatorOrContainer>::flat_tree(bool, InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >*; Value = boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> >; KeyOfValue = boost::container::dtl::select1st<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = boost::container::new_allocator<boost::container::dtl::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >]’
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/flat_map.hpp:347:8:   required from ‘boost::container::flat_map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>::flat_map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, T> >) [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; T = std::unique_ptr<Base>; Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; AllocatorOrContainer = void]’
[build] ../../test/qtest.cpp:40:5:   required from here
[build] /home/me/.conan2/p/b/boosteb63be9b0ca18/p/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:173:25: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Base; _Dp = std::default_delete<Base>]’
[build]   173 |       : first(x.first), second(x.second)
[build]       |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/memory:76,
[build]                  from ../../test/qtest.cpp:2:
[build] /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:468:7: note: declared here
[build]   468 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
[build]       |       ^~~~~~~~~~
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


please show a [mre] and the full compiler error message

Does std::flat_map have the same problem?

@Eljay it's not a problem of any particular container, it's a limitation in initialiser lists that they don't work with movable types

@bustus_primus In response to your edit, the problems is exactly the same. The problem isn't in moving the container. It's in initializing it using the initializer list in the first place! See here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76f9d5268fa5a2fe
